# Is the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3+n}$ convergent or divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Is the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3+n}$ convergent or divergent? And how? What method is required? Thanks.

Comment: Please indicate what you have tried.

Comment: I tried splitting up the denominator by factoring out an n and then tried partial fractions, but then got stuck doing partial fractions with the n^2+n

Comment: If you're talking about integrating, you can write $1/(x^3 + x) = x/x^2(x^2 + 1)$ and make the substitution $u = x^2$ *before* applying the partial fraction method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^3+x}dx$

$\frac{1}{x(x^2+1)}=\frac{A}{x}+\frac{Bx+C}{x^2+1}=\frac{Ax^2+A+Bx^2+Cx}{x(x^2+1)}$
Therfore, $A+B=0, C=0, A=1$, then $B=-1$.

$\int \frac{1}{x^3+x}dx=\int \frac{dx}{x}-\int \frac{x dx}{x^2+1}=\ln x -\frac{1}{2}\ln (x^2+1)=\ln\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$

For $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^3+x}dx=\lim_{x \to \infty}\ln\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}-\ln\frac{1}{\sqrt{1^2+1}}=0-\ln\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}<\infty.$
Integral is convergent, therefore the series too.

Comment: Oh..... I forgot that I needed Bx+C not just B. Thanks so much @kmitov

Answer (score 5):

$1/(n^3+n) \leq 1/n^3$. So by comparison test we see that this series converges

Comment: Is there a way to do it without comparison test because we have yet to learn that.

Comment: What are the methods that you have learnt?

Comment: integral test, partial sum stuff, p-series, & geometric series. If those are even correct methods..

Comment: Try the integral test on this one. What function should you be looking at?

Comment: @Logan Do you know the comparison test for improper integrals?

Comment: @voldemort i should be looking at the n^3+n right?

Comment: @user121926 no we haven't learned comparison test.

Comment: @Logan: You need a function. Replace $n$ by $x$. You have to integrate the function from where to where?

Comment: @voldemort from 1 to infinity

Comment: @Logan: Correct.